# Android: ViewModel "computed observable"

Tags: android-viewmodel

Can you have computed observables in Android (like you can, say, in VueJS)?

```
class MainActivityViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    val speedInput = MutableLiveData<Double>() // Actual value from sensor input.
    val speedFactor = MutableLiveData<Double>() // To be set from shared preferences

    val speed = speedInput * speedFactor // The value we need is computed from two observables.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a need to combine several LiveData in one there is a [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) for this. It can take several LiveData as a sources and "compute" its own value based on these sources (so to get its value you should observe it as well).

Something like this:

```
.........
val speed = MediatorLiveData<Double>()

speed.addSource(speedInput) { value ->
    speed.value = computeSpeed(speedInput, speedFactor)
}
speed.addSource(speedFactor) { value ->
    speed.value = computeSpeed(speedInput, speedFactor)
}
.........

fun computeSpeed(speedInput: MutableliveData<Double>, speedFactor: MutableliveData<Double>) = speedInput.value * speedFactor.value
```